# How to call a static method on a generic class

Tags: java, generics

So i have a function that takes a generic and a parameter.
This generic is not an instance, but a typename.
I need to call a static method of the class corrensponding to the typename.

```
public <T extends Base> void Process(Callback functionInterface)
{
  functionInterface.call(T.GetStaticParams());
}
```

I know that all possible T classes have a static method GetStaticParams(), but the Java compiler does not know how to find the function specified.

I have tried having GetStaticParams() in Base and all Children classes, but then only the method in the Base class gets called.

Comment: You need to also pass `Class<T>` and invoke the static method via reflection.

Comment: I don't think this is possible due to type erasure.

Comment: What's the problem you're solving with this? Seems roundabout